# PhpStorm, не отображается главное меню в новом окне. Debian KDE

Tags: debian, phpstorm, jetbrains, kde

Если открыть один экземпляр PhpStorm, то всё работает корректно, меню показывается, но если открыть проект в новом окне (через кнопку, указанную на скрине)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То откроется новое окно, но уже без главного меню. Пропадают кнопки закрытия расширения и сворачивания окна, а также все пункты меню.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверил, это также работает и в остальных IDE от JetBrains: WebStorm и Goland. Раньше всё было ок, но в какой-то момент возникла такая проблема